# Not able to claim EOS tokens through MyEtherWallet

Tags: contract-invocation, tokens, myetherwallet, ico

I was following this guide to acquire EOS tokens:
https://steemit.com/eos/@sandwich/contributing-to-eos-token-sale-with-myetherwallet-and-contract-inner-workings

Did step one first. Seemed to work fine (at least the money went out of my wallet).

Then I went to Step 2: Claim EOS Tokens.
I've done all that and the token didn't show up in the "Load Tokens" section.

And then, I noticed that when I load "EOS Contribution" on MyEtherWallet contracts section it shows a different step-by-step instruction:

```
Generate EOS Key-pair
Register / Map your EOS Key
    Select register
    Enter your EOS Public Key <--- CAREFUL! EOS PUBLIC KEY!
    Unlock wallet
    Amount to Send: 0 · Gas Limit: at least 90000
Fund EOS Contract on Send Page
    Go to Send Ether & Tokens Page
    Unlock same wallet you are unlocking here.
    Send Amount you want to Contribute to 0xd0a6E6C54DbC68Db5db3A091B171A77407Ff7ccf
    Gas Limit: at least 90000
Claim EOS Tokens
    Select claimAll.
    Unlock wallet
    Amount to Send: 0 · Gas Limit: at least 90000
```

After seeing that I tried to turn to this different step-by-step and tried registering my EOS Key-pair.
Did as it recommended above, when I check on Etherscan, transaction was successfull.

Since the "Fund EOS Contract on Send Page" was already done, I jumped to "Claim EOS Tokens". I follow the instructions, I get a "wallet successfully decrypted" but when I try to make this 0 ETH transaction it never runs through.

So, my question is:

a) Is there a problem on the sequence of events? I should have maped my EOS Keys prior to Funding the EOS Contract? If that's a problem, what happens now? I lose my money?

b) If there is not a problem with the sequence of events, why I'm not able to claim my tokens?

Can someone shine some light on it?

Comment: There is no problem with reversing the sequence of events. You can register and update your EOS key pair tied to an Ethereum key pair at any time. What it sounds like to me is you funded the most recent period and tried to claim before the period was over.

If you go back and claim the specific period number you contributed to, you should be able to claim your tokens. Alternatively you can claimAll, although that costs a lot more gas to perform.

You can see more data about the periods here: https://eosscan.io/